# Using bind variables in large insert statements

Tags: sql, c, oracle, plsql, oracle-call-interface

I am inheriting an application which has to read data from various types of files and use the OCI interface to move the data into an Oracle database. Most of the tables in question have about 40-50 columns, so the SQL insert statements become pretty lengthy.

When I inherited this code, it basically built up the insert statements via a series of `strcat`s as a C string, then passed it to the appropriate OCI functions to set up and execute the statement. However, since much of the data is read directly from files into the column values, this leaves the application open to easy SQL injection. So I am trying to use bind variables to solve this problem.

In every example OCI application I can find, each variable is statically allocated and bound individually. This would lead to quite a bit of boilerplate, however and I'd like to reduce it to some sort of looping construct. So my solution is to, for each table, create a static array of strings containing the names of the table columns:

```
const char const *TABLE_NAME[N_COLS] = {
    "COL_1",
    "COL_2",
    "COL_3",
    ...
    "COL_N"
};
```

along with a short function that makes a placeholder out of a column name:

```
void makePlaceholder(char *buf, const char *col);
// "COLUMN_NAME" -> ":column_name"
```

So I then loop through each array and bind my values to each column, generating the placeholders as I go. One potential problem here is that, because the types of each column vary, I bind everything as `SQLT_STR` (strings) and thus expect Oracle to convert to the proper datatype on insertion.

So, my question(s) are:

1. What is the proper/idiomatic (if such a thing exists for SQL/OCI) to use bind variables for SQL insert statements with a large number of columns/params? More generally, what is the best way to use OCI to make this type of large insert statement?
2. Do large numbers of bind calls have a significant cost in efficiency compared to building and using vanilla C strings?
3. Is there any risk in binding all variables as strings and allowing Oracle to make the proper type conversion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the C aspects of this. My answer will be from a DBA perspective.

Question 2:
Always use bind variables. It prevent SQL-injection and enhances performance.

The performance aspect is often overlooked by programmers. When Oracle receives a SQL it makes a hash of the entire SQL-text and looks in it's internal repository of execution plans to see if it has one. If bind variables was used it the SQL-text will be the same each time you run the query, not matter what the value of a variable is. However if you have concatenated the string your self Oracle will hash the SQL-text including content of (what you aught to have put in) variables, getting a unique hash every time. So if you do a query one million times Oracle will if you used bind variables make one execution plan, while if you did not use bind variables it will make one million execution plans and waste loads of resources doing that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So if I understand correctly, this performance enhancement would only apply if *all* columns are bound, correct? So even choosing not to bind a single column out of many would result in a different SQL-text and thus negate the performance boost?